# Gradient Map in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, gradient

Is there a way to create a gradient map effect in illustrator?
I tried different bledning modes but I cant get it to look the the photoshop version.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You want to add that effect to a raster image?

Comment: It may be possible to achieve some similar effect. However, it would *greatly* depend upon the artwork. The gradient map in Photoshop is really just a hue adjustment on a scale. That *can* be done in Illustrator (not with blending modes).

Comment: Manually build a gradient mesh over your art.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default no. There might be some plugins to do this.

However it wouldnt really work eactly the same way as in a raster image, since vectors dont work exactly the same. I think we have a question on why a curves adjustment doesnt really seem to produce the same thing in vectors as in raster graphics somewhere.

Comment: any alternative way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is! I just found out as well. Here's what you gonna do:

- create two rectangles, same size as your image and with the desired colors (can be edited later).
- place your image on top of one of them and select both.
- on the opacity panel, click "Make mask". It will convert your image into B&W and use the data to create transparency on your rectangle.
- Place the new group on top of the other rectangle.
- Voilà!

Now you may want to play around with the "Invert mask" option, depending on hat colors you chose. You can change the colors of the elements individually or selecting them all and using the Recolor button on the Properties panel.

[image]

Comment: This is *not* the same as a gradient map. This is more like a `Multiply` blending mode. (which you can do easily without the opacity mask - i.e. transparency panel) There's a vast difference between this and an *actual* gradient map. I'd suggest you look at a gradient map in Photoshop using an *actual* gradient and *not* a single, flat, color.

Comment: [For Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA2gT.png) . In addition, add a third color to the gradient and the difference is [more apparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms0sN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround using Illustrator documents inside Photoshop,

One of the reasons we need to use vector art is to maintain resolutionless edges on text, flat art.. you know.. vector outlines.

Complete your art in Illustrator. Grayscale is best if you can think ahead far enough.  Then PLACE it in Photoshop.  When it asks you whether you want pixels or smart objects, pick smart object.  This creates a link to the Illustrator document and keeps that work intact as is on the output side, with your gradient map effect.   Some blending modes in the parent document may not work, I haven't used this technique on documents with complex blending options in layers.